# Adding certain elements of list of lists together, keeping others intact

Tags: python, list

Have some data in the form of a list of lists. So e.g:

```
[[2.94, 0.389, 0.167, -2.75], [1.74, -0.211, -0.474, -1.37], 1.091753800499324]
```

Where I would like to create a new list which consists of the first two elements of the list above combined togheter, with the third element intact. e.g.

```
   [[4.68, 0.17800000000000002, -0.30699999999999994, -4.12], 1.091753800499324]
```

Have tried a whole bunch of ways to go about adding them, but unable to get it right without disturbing the last element of the list.

Comment: can you show the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Know has been solved but essentially got mine to create a list with all the elements except it was all one list. And no-where near as consice & elegant as solution above. I'm new to programming and so still haven't encountered these new methods yet. Basically I created an empty list. Then would append each element in the list above one at a time, until the whole thing has been created. And issue was having that the empty list would contain all the variables as 1 list and not a list of list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
data = [[2.94, 0.389, 0.167, -2.75], [1.74, -0.211, -0.474, -1.37], 1.091753800499324]
new_data = [[sum(x) for x in zip(data[0], data[1])]] + [data[-1]]

new_data
[[4.68, 0.17800000000000002, -0.30699999999999994, -4.12], 1.091753800499324]
```

Or more generally, if you have more than 2 lists to sum and always want to keep the last element out:

```
new_data = [[sum(x) for x in zip(*data[:-1])]] + [data[-1]]
new_data
[[4.68, 0.17800000000000002, -0.30699999999999994, -4.12], 1.091753800499324]
```

#### Step by step:

- Get all the elements of the list, except the last one:

```
data[:-1]
[[2.94, 0.389, 0.167, -2.75], [1.74, -0.211, -0.474, -1.37]]
```

- Zip two-by-two all the elements of all the lists:
  `zip(*data[:-1])` is the same as `zip(data[0], data[1], data[2], ..., data[n-1])`
  This function yields something like this:

```
zip(*data[:-1])
<zip at 0x1b4b93673c8>
```

To see the content, you should pass a `list`:

```
list(zip(*data[:-1]))
[(2.94, 1.74), (0.389, -0.211), (0.167, -0.474), (-2.75, -1.37)]
```

As you can see, the elements are paired two-by-two, yielding a list of tuples.

- Now do it inside a **list comprehension**, and sum every tuple:

```
[sum(x) for x in zip(*data[:-1])]
[4.68, 0.17800000000000002, -0.30699999999999994, -4.12]
```

- Concatenate this list with the last element. To do it, the last element also need to be a list, that's why we need to get the last element as a list using `[data[-1]]`:

```
[[sum(x) for x in zip(*data[:-1])]] + [data[-1]]
[[4.68, 0.17800000000000002, -0.30699999999999994, -4.12], 1.091753800499324]
```

Comment: Many thanks! My wrong solution took like 10 lines, and your right one took 2!

Comment: You're welcome. So would be good to accept this as the right answer if you could.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip

```py
output_list = []

input_list = [[2.94, 0.389, 0.167, -2.75], [1.74, -0.211, -0.474, -1.37], 1.091753800499324]
nested_list1 = input_list[0]
nested_list2 = input_list[1]

add_list = []
for element1, element2 in zip(nested_list1, nested_list2):
    add_list.append(element1 + element2)

output_list.append(add_list)
output_list.append(input_list[2])

print(output_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst=[[2.94, 0.389, 0.167, -2.75], [1.74, -0.211, -0.474, -1.37], 1.091753800499324]
q=len(lst[0])
w=len(lst[1])
for i in range(max(q,w)):
    if i==q:
        for j in range(i,w):
            lst[0].append(lst[1][j])
        break
    if i==w:
        break
    lst[0][i]=lst[0][i]+lst[1][i]
del lst[1]
print(lst)
# this code should work even if first and second element is of different length
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
in_data = [[2.94, 0.389, 0.167, -2.75], [1.74, -0.211, -0.474, -1.37], 1.091753800499324]

out_data = [x+y for (x,y) in zip(in_data[0], in_data[1])] + [in_data[2]]
```